# Commutative monoid from 'algebra' package on Hackage

Tags: haskell, hackage, abstract-algebra

The documentation for [algebra/2.1.1.2/doc/html](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/algebra/2.1.1.2/doc/html/Numeric-Algebra-Class.html#t:Multiplicative) shows a colossal number of type classes.

How do I declare that a structure in question must be equipped with a commutative associative operation and a unit/identity element, but without anything else (inverses, distributivity etc)?

I'm thinking of

```
reduce :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
```

but instances of Data.Monoid are not supposed to be commutative and I want users of my function to see that they need commutativity for the function to work by looking at the type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(Abelian m, Monoidal m)`

It might seem that `Monoidal` is much more than you want, but it is all based on `Natural` being a `Semiring`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that package provides a Commutative class, so correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like it's just a matter of specifying a second typeclass:

```
reduce :: (Monoid m, Commutative m) => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
```

Comment: `Commutative` talks about the action of the `Multiplicative` class, not `Monoid`. You could use `(Commutative m, Unital m)` to get a multiplicative commutative monoid that works with `(*)` and `one`, or `(Abelian m, Monoidal m)` to get a commutative monoid that works with `(+)` and `zero`.