# Representing commutative semigroups polynomials in Haskell

Tags: haskell, symbolic-math, algebra

I'm trying to represent terms like the following:

```
a0 <> a1 <> ... <> an-1
```

Where `ai` must be element of a commutative Semigroup. For this one can choose a data representation like the following:

```
newtype SemigroupPolynomial a = SP Map a Integer
```

where the map contains the different terms of the polynomial and its count.

In this way, we can represent the sum

```
3 + 3 + 6
```

as (assuming `OverloadedLists`):

```
SP [(3, 2), (6, 1)]
```

But also we can represent terms like:

```
3 * 3 * 6
```

The `SemigroupPolynomial` could be an instance of `Semigroup`:

```
instance ??? a => Semigroup (SemigroupPolynomial a) where
    (MP p0) <> (MP p1) = 
        MP $ Map.filter (0/=) $ Map.unionWith (+) p0 p1
```

No the question is which constraints do I have to put in `???` so that:

1. The `<>` operation is commutative and associative.
2. It can be used to represent sums and products, as exemplified above.

A similar question on how to represent commutative Monoids [was already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289746/commutative-monoid-from-algebra-package-on-hackage). However it seems that the constraint `(Abelian m, Monoidal m)` might be too strong (I don't require a zero element), and it will prevent me to use this to represent products.

Comment: You don't really need the instance to know anything about commutativity, do you? Sounds like a law-thing that would normally just be expressed in documentation. (I know, this isn't elegant, but...) What you do need is the much uglier `Ord` constraint in oder to use `Map`.

Comment: By representing a sum like `2 + 6 + 2` as a map I'm loosing information about the order of the terms, so I do need the commutativity constraint I think. Maybe not in the `Semigroup` instance, but somewhere I would think...

Comment: Well, you basically just act _as if_ it's commutative. Whether the key type really _is_ commutative is another question. I agree that in principle this _should_ be expressed by a dedicated class (basically an empty subclass of `Semigroup` that doesn't add any methods, only a law), but I'm not sure if that's practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leftroundabout has commented, you don't *need* a constraint here.  Don't be fooled by the word "constraint".  In Haskell, the primary purpose of constraints isn't to constrain the behavior of a particular type or operation in some manner.  Rather, it's to constrain the set of types that a function will accept to those types that support a set of operations.

When I write:

```
fmapTwice :: (Functor f) => (a -> a) -> f a -> f a
fmapTwice f = fmap (f . f)
```

I'm not really constraining the type `f` to act like a functor and obey the rules required of functors.  Rather, I'm constraining the `fmapTwice` function to only apply to types `f` that support the `fmap` operation.

Nothing stops some jerk from writing:

```
data Foo a = Foo a | NoFoo deriving (Show)
instance Functor Foo where
    fmap _ _ = NoFoo   -- invalid functor violates:  fmap id = id
```

and applying my function to this invalid functor:

```
> fmapTwice (*2) (Foo 10)
NoFoo
>
```

Haskell relies on programmer discipline to ensure that something declared as having a `Functor` instance is a well behaved functor.

In your example, the instance:

```
import Data.Semigroup
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)

data SemigroupPolynomial a = SP (Map a Integer) deriving (Show)
instance (Ord a) => Semigroup (SemigroupPolynomial a) where
    (SP p0) <> (SP p1) = 
        SP $ Map.filter (0/=) $ Map.unionWith (+) p0 p1
```

doesn't require any constraints other than `Ord a`, to ensure that `a` can be used as a `Map` key.

Now, it's up to you to make sure you only use your `SemigroupPolynomial` to represent commutative operations:

```
foldSP :: (a -> a -> a) -> SemigroupPolynomial a -> a
foldSP f (SP m) = foldr1 f $ concatMap (\(a, n) -> replicate (fromIntegral n) a)
                                       (Map.assocs m)

main = do let sp = singleton 3 <> singleton 3 <> singleton 6
          print sp
          print $ foldSP (*) sp
          print $ foldSP (+) sp
          print $ foldSP (-) sp   -- wrong, but it's your own damn fault
```

If you want to somehow introduce a requirement of commutativity into your data type, one way of doing it (that doesn't involve Haskell "constraints" at all) is to write something like:

```
data CommutativeOp a = CO (a -> a -> a)
foldSP :: CommutativeOp a -> SemigroupPolynomial a -> a
foldSP (CO f) (SP m) = <same as above>
```

Now, as long as you realize that when you write:

```
plusOp = CO (+)
timesOp = CO (*)
```

you are making a declaration that `(+)` and `(*)` are commutative operations, this will ensure that `foldSP` is only applied to such operations:

```
main = do let sp = singleton 3 <> singleton 3 <> singleton 6
          print $ foldSP plusOp sp
          print $ foldSP timesOp sp
```

If you want to somehow introduce a commutativity constraint on the type `a` to ensure that `SemigroupPolynomial a` is a valid representation, then you can't do this for `a` equal to `Int`, obviously, since it depends on which binary operation `Int -> Int -> Int` is used for the fold.

Instead, you need to embed the operation into the type, perhaps using `newtype`s that represent the operation, like `Sum` or `Product` in `Data.Semigroup`.  Then, you can introduce a type class (with no operations) to represent the commutativity constraint:

```
class Commutative a
instance Commutative (Sum a)
instance Commutative (Product a)
instance (Ord a, Commutative b) => SemigroupPolynomial b where
    ...definition on (<>) as above...
```

and now the fold operation would use the operation implicit in the newtype (here, just using the monoid instance):

```
foldSP' :: (Monoid a) => SemigroupPolynomial a -> a
foldSP' (SP m) = mconcat $ concatMap (\(a, n) -> replicate (fromIntegral n) a)
                                     (Map.assocs m)
```

Maybe this is what you wanted.  If so, the full example looks like this:

```
import Data.Semigroup
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)

newtype SemigroupPolynomial a = SP (Map a Integer) deriving (Show)

class Commutative a
instance Commutative (Sum a)
instance Commutative (Product a)
instance (Ord a, Commutative a) => Semigroup (SemigroupPolynomial a) where
    (SP p0) <> (SP p1) = 
        SP $ Map.filter (0/=) $ Map.unionWith (+) p0 p1

singleton :: a -> SemigroupPolynomial a
singleton x = SP $ Map.singleton x 1

foldSP' :: (Monoid a) => SemigroupPolynomial a -> a
foldSP' (SP m) = mconcat $ concatMap (\(a, n) -> replicate (fromIntegral n) a)
                                     (Map.assocs m)

main = do let sp1 = singleton (Sum 3) <> singleton (Sum 3) <> singleton (Sum 6)
          print sp1
          print (foldSP' sp1)
          let sp2 = singleton (Product 3) <> singleton (Product 3) 
                          <> singleton (Product 6)
          print sp2
          print (foldSP' sp2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've constructed there is a free monoid, which is in turn just a list. You could probably use `[(a, Integer)]` rather than a map and it would be fine for some use cases. Since Haskell doesn't have dependent types, I doubt there will be anything nicer in terms of types.

> No the question is which constraints do I have to put in ??? so that:
>
> The <> operation is commutative and associative.
>
> It can be used to represent sums and products, as exemplified above.

You should probably create a `Ring` typeclass, or use that of [numeric-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.2/docs/Algebra-Ring.html). That will let users know your data type is associative, and has addition and multiplication. There's not any great type-level way to indicate these to my knowledge. You could use a property test to make sure that everything worked via [hspec](https://hspec.github.io) or a similar library.

> However it seems that the constraint (Abelian m, Monoidal m) might be too strong (I don't require a zero element), and it will prevent me to use this to represent products.

There's no algebraic structure associated with polynomials "over" a semigroup, so you may have to implement that yourself. Since you say that `<>` is commutative, your elements *will* satisfy `Abelian m`. It's just a question of adding a unit.